# regex for passphrase

Tags: regex, validation, passphrase

I'm a newbie to regex and trying to create a regex to validate pass phrases. I would like to validate that the pass phrase has:

- n number of words or more
- words should be separated by spaces
- words, each with n characters or more
- a number in at least one of the words
- at least one special character in one of the words

This is what what I have so far

```
^(?=.*?((?:.*?\b[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,40}\b)\s*){3,})(?=.*?[@#$%^&+=])(?=.*?[0-9]).*$
```

It matches this `Pe2sI#sHy?ThYulU#` phrase that does not have at least 3 words (no spaces). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would replace your last requirement with a minimum length. One benefit of passphrases is that they obviate the need to remember a bunch of crazy numbers and special characters, yet maintain a high level of variability because they're very long.

Comment: That's true but leaving out special characters leaves the pass phrase vulnerable to attacks using statistical analysis on word usage especially because people tend to use a limited set of words. Adding at least one special character improves the entropy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `\s+` instead of `\s*`. The latter allows zero spaces, the former requires at least one. But your regex is overly complicated. Try this:

```
^                 # Start of string
(?=.*\d)          # Assert at least one digit
(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])  # Assert at least one special char
\s*               # Optional leading whitespace
(?:               # Match...
 \S{2,}           #  at least 2 non-spaces
 \s+              #  at least 1 whitespace
){2,}             # at least 2 times
\S{2,}            # Match at least 2 non-spaces (making 3 "words" minimum)
```

Comment: +1 because I was building a similar one. I would use `[[:punct:]]` for the special char instead.

Comment: That appears not to work, with \s+ the phrase "testing# 123 lets test" will not validate unless I move the "#" to the last word. I need at least one special character on any word. Thanks for your help.

Comment: sorry replied be4 I saw your edits with the suggested regex. I'll test it out now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A little late to this, so this is just an observation.

This is a take-off on @Tim Pietzcker's method.
Although 'words' can be anything, if you want to require at least
3 words have [a-zA-Z0-9]{2,40} characters imbedded, you could do this.

```
^                      # String start
(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])       # Assert 1 special char
(?=.*\d)               # Assert 1 digit
(?:                    # Special 'Word Group'  -- Need 2 words
   .*                     # Any char, 0 or more times
   [a-zA-Z0-9]{2,40}      # Alpha/num char, 2 to 40 times
   .*                     # Any char, 0 or more times
   \s                     # a whitespace, only 1 required
){2}                   # 'Word Group' end, do 2 times
.*                     # Any char, 0 or more times
[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,40}      # Alpha/num char, 2 to 40 times -- Need 1 word
```

This should match at least 3 special [a-zA-Z0-9]{2,40} words separated by at least 1 space
including a digit and special character.

**update**

Yes, you can combine it into a single group done {3} times in 2 ways I know of.

Use a capture buffer as a flag

```
^(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])(?=.*\d)(?:(?:(?!\1)|\s).*[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,40}().*){3} 
                                                       ^          ^
---------------------------------------   

^                      # String start
(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])       # Assert 1 special char
(?=.*\d)               # Assert 1 digit
(?:                    # Special 'Word Group'
   (?:                    #.. grping start ....
        (?!\1)              # Either capt group 1 is UN-DEFINED
      | \s                  # OR, require a whitespace
    )                     #.. grping end ....
   .*                     # Any char, 0 or more times
   [a-zA-Z0-9]{2,40}      # Alpha/num char, 2 to 40 times
   ()                     # DEFINE Capture group 1
   .*                     # Any char, 0 or more times
){3}                   # 'Word Group' end, do 3 times
```

Or, by using a conditional

```
^(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])(?=.*\d)(?:(?(1)\s).*([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,40}).*){3}
                                                   ^         ^
---------------------------------------   

^                      # String start
(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])       # Assert 1 special char
(?=.*\d)               # Assert 1 digit
(?:                    # Special 'Word Group'
   (?(1)\s)               # Conditional, require a whitespace if capture group 1 captured anything
   .*                     # Any char, 0 or more times
   ([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,40})    # Capture group 1, Alpha/num char, 2 to 40 times
   .*                     # Any char, 0 or more times
){3}                   # 'Word Group' end, do 3 times
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer has met the extra requirement of word-length-limitation. Is there a different way expressing it so that if there's a need to change the word-length & number-of-words requirements, then you only have to change 2 places or less like the original expression. I'm asking this for the sake of readability and avoiding errors by anyone reading my code. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: @jimm312 - Sure, that shouldn't be too hard. Check the update. Cheers!